# PHP: Process multiple requests at the same time

Tags: php, multithreading, codeigniter

I am developing a project where database and some config files are created dynamically when admin approves client registration.

So when admin clicks approve, an ajax call is sent and after the data is validated, I am posting a response to user using

```
header('Connection: close');
header('Content-Length: '.ob_get_length());
ob_end_flush();
ob_flush();
flush();
```

and then call a function `$this->RegistrationModel->continue_Setup($id);` to continue the actual setup.

Now I want to approve one more user. The same process gets executed again.
My question is until the 1st request get's completed, the second request is not going to be executed. So is there any way that I can handle this requests in parallel ?

I am using the codeigniter frame work.

```
 $.ajax({
            url     : base_url+'/approve',
            method  : "POST",
            async   : true,
            data    :{ 'UnVkaUNTUkYtVC1B' : 'f0ac036e3714e46f39f9c665a43141e6','var':id},
            success:function(data){
                data = $.parseJSON(data);
                }
            },
            error:function(){

            }
        });
```

Comment: From the server side point of view there is no limitation that could lead to such requests NOT getting processed in (quasi) parallel manner. Actually that pretty much is what http servers ar good at: responding to all incoming requests simultaneously. So unless you have taken special caution there is nothing to be done. Things are different on the client side, of course, but that is nothing we can say anything about, is it?

Comment: Yeah right. I'm working on this in localhost with Apache & MySQL. 
Is this because of my localhost ? 
if not, what would be the solution ?

Comment: A local http server is still an http server. As said: I do not see a limitation, _except if you implemented one._ Question is: why do you think such limitation exists?

Comment: That said: it might actually be that your http server has such limitation (we do not know your setup...): you should check the limitations in the configuration (which depends on _which_ http server you use). Are there multiple listening child processes / threads or is that limited?

Comment: @arkascha Why i think there is some limitation because, i had activated a user, when i try to activate the second user, i don't get a response. 
I keep tracking the database which is being created by the above mentioned function.
After the entire database has been created by the 1st request, i get a response from my second request. 
That's why i think i'm unable to handle two requests at a time.

Comment: Let's keep the wording clean here, otherwise this gets confusing: What _exactly_ do you mean by "I don't get a response."? Do you get an error? A white page? Does the client "hang"? And next: what do you mean by "After the entire database has been created by the 1st request"? Surely it is _not_ the database that get's created? That should obviously exist for the whole application from the start?

Comment: ok. Let me get it clear. For suppose as 1st request, i had sent an ajax call which gets a response (basically a json response containing a message) and then executes sleep('60');  when i send another ajax call as a second request, i don't get any response which is a json reponse message as i got for 1st request until the 1st request's sleep gets completed. Hope you understand. If not  please let me know.

Comment: After undergoing some of the troubleshooting, i am able to create multiple request using multiple browsers before completing the previous requests but not with the same browser.
So do you think there is some thing limited in browser ?

Comment: Ah, ok, that sounds like an issue on the client side, not on the server side. Test yourself: open the browsers development console (typically F12) and in there the "Network" tab. Now trigger the request pair and observe: when does the second request actually get sent? Immediately or after the 60 seconds? I bet the second, because you trigger it in the success handler of the first request or because your requests get queued on the client side.

Comment: As you said, i already tried posting the 1st request and immediately the second one. What i see is the second one is also getting posted immediately. But the response gets back only once the 1st request is completed.
Even when i try to refresh the page, the page gets refreshed only after the request gets completed.

Comment: What framework do you use on the client side to perform those ajax requests?

Comment: I'm using php framework codeigniter. So posting ajax call is in simple jquery.

Comment: That does not really help. Please add the relevant parts of your client side logic to the questioon above. Thanks.

Comment: I had updated my question with my ajax code.

Comment: I asked this a couple of months ago look at here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31815502/how-to-handle-multiple-requests-in-php